# finding an anchor with a certain attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I'm trying to find an anchor inside a div that posses a specific attribute, but the jquery code is for some looking at the hreef value of the anchor, not the anchor itself. This is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#ax_campaign_nav a").each(function (i) {
                if (this.attr('data-ident') == "ax_models") {
                        this.hide();
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And my link looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-ident="ax_models" onclick="scrollToAnchor('#a_ax_models')">+ Model Bios</a>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#ax_campaign_nav a[data-ident=ax_models]").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your are trying to get the data-indent attribute you probably want to check this out:

http://api.jquery.com/data/

```
$("#ax_campaign_nav a").data("indent") === "ax_models"
```

.data() was a new feature added in 1.4.3 of jQuery.  It is very nice and allows you to use the data-key="value" attributes quite nicely.

Also be sure to use '===' because it checks for the type as well as the value.  Most of the time you should always use '===' and '!==' except for a very few specific scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).attr("data-ident")` and `$(this).hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing more than:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ax_campaign_nav a[data-intent=ax_models]").each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```